# grant ssis_admin on SSISDB to <username> isn't working

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I am using SQL Server 2012 version of database. I am trying to write a query which grants SSIS_ADMIN on SSISDB to a user. Below is my query

```
GRANT SSIS_ADMIN ON SSISDB TO User1
```

But eventually, i am getting an error

> "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near 'SSIS_ADMIN'."

I have searched enough to frame a grant query but I am unable to find one. So, how do I grant user "database role membership" permissions on databases.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `SSIS_ADMIN` is a role, not a priviledge. You need to add the user to the role

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to add `user1` to `ssis_admin` database role..

try this..

```
use ssisdb
go

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'ssis_admin', 'user1';
```

you can use Grant to give [permissions specified here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178569.aspx)  and not to assign roles to users..

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO MelanieK;
```

Comment: Hi TheGameiswar, thanks for the reply. I have a database SSISDB and a User "User1". I want to give User1 a SSIS_ADMIN permission on SSISDB.

Comment: add that user1 to db and add him to role like i mentioned in question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the SSMS GUI:

1. Open SSMS
2. Right Click on User i.e. User1
3. Properties>User Mapping
4. Check/Select Database SSISDB
5. Select `ssis_admin` from database roles

OR

```
USE [SSISDB]
GO
ALTER ROLE [ssis_admin] ADD MEMBER [User1]
GO
```